# Indenting a YAML sequence inside a mapping

Tags: yaml

Should the following be valid?

```
parent:
- child
- child
```

So what we have is a sequence of values inside a mapping.

The specific question is about whether the indentation for the 2nd and 3rd lines is valid.  The Ruby YAML.dump generated this code, but the Yaml parser [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/yamlparser.aspx) rejects it, because the child lines are not indented.

i.e. it wants something like:

```
parent:
  - child
  - child
```

Who is right?

Looking at the YAML spec, it's certainly not obvious, and the line

> The “-”, “?” and “:” characters used to denote block collection entries are perceived by people to be part of the indentation

doesn't help much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, that is legal YAML. The relevant text from the spec is [here](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2799784):

> Since people perceive the “-” indicator as indentation, nested block sequences may be indented by one less space to compensate, except, of course, if nested inside another block sequence (block-out context vs. block-in context).

and the subsequent [example 8.22](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2800008):

```
sequence: !!seq
- entry
- !!seq
 - nested
mapping: !!map
 foo: bar
```

Comment: Yes, the spec is less ambiguous here.  Thanks.